# append application context path to the hyperlink in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, applicationcontext

I added the following command to application.properties file.

```
server.contextPath=/SpringBootOracle
```

Now, I have a hyperlink in the html page as shown below

```
<a href="/product/new">New Product</a>
```

Every time when I click the link, it will jump to

```
localhost:8080/product/new
```

Is there any way I can append the application context to the link so that I can get below?

```
localhost:8080/SpringBootOracle/product/new
```

Comment: spring boot version?

Comment: @sajib it's 1.5.1.RELEASE

Comment: @sajib Yes. It's thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use thymeleaf then try with this:

```
<a th:href="@{/product/new}">New Product</a>
```